# Implicit declaration of function is invalid in C99 - error when installing software on macOS

Tags: c, macos, cmake, compilation, c99

I am trying to install Elmer FEM software on my MacOS 12.6.
I use:
XCode Version 14.0.1 (14A400)
Apple clang version 14.0.0 (clang-1400.0.29.102)
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 13.2.0) 13.2.0

I followed the instructions for installation and compilation, and keep getting this error:

```
/Users/victor/elmer/elmerfem/fem/src/Load.c:591:3: error: implicit declaration of function 'var_copy_transpose' is invalid in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
  var_copy_transpose(name,values,*nrows,*ncols);
  ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [fem/src/CMakeFiles/elmersolver.dir/Load.c.o] Error 1
```

When googleing this question, the standard tipp is to include <stdlib.h> and try to declare the function before its first use. Both is the case, and it can't be a problem with the Load.c file itself because thousands of people are using it and it works. So there must be a problem with my compiler or so... Has somebody an idea how to solve this problem? I'm already spending days to install it... Thank you so much!

Paths (gcc alias and cc alias) in .bash_profile are set (from instructions):

```
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/
    alias gcc='gcc-10'
    alias cc='gcc-10'
```

macports is deleted for now because there arose an error (homebrew and macports prefix, "define one of them")

Comment: Including <stdlib.h> would only help for standard library functions declared by that header, not for `var_copy_transpose`. The code needs to declare `var_copy_transpose` before the function is called. Normally, such functions should be declared in one of the project's header files if the function definition is in a different c file.

Comment: Instead of `stdlib.h` you need to include the headers that come with the library you are using and that provides that function.

Comment: It's amazing that such a project does not follow basic C programming guidelines.

Comment: The totally dangerous alternative is to add the option `-Wno-implicit-function-declaration` for code older than C99. Then you will not *see* the error.

Comment: @Gerhardh In this particular case there is no header that declares this function, and the error is from compiling the library itself. The problem is entirely with the library and not with the user.

Comment: The first thing you should do is submit a bug report to the library maintainers. Then if you don't want to wait for them to fix it, you may try to fix it yourself and then perhaps send them a patch. In order to fix the problem, you need to create a declaration of the function in question. It should be placed in a header file which `Load.c` needs to include, but it's hard to tell which exact header it should be. The next best thing is to place the declaration somewhere near the top of `Load.c` itself.

Comment: Do a simple text search for `var_copy_transpose` in Load.c as well as all the .h header files which Load.c *might* #include. I think it's likely you'll find that either the function declaration or an include which contains it has been conditionally excluded from the build using a `#if` or similar conditional. You might be missing a configuration setting somewhere.